# JSfiddle not working on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I've got a Jsfiddle working correctly, however when i copy the code into my webpage and the CSS, JavaScript files the code does not work. Does anyone have any idea how to correctly copy the code into the webpage to display it correctly? Thanks

jsfiddle.net/ajs122/dwm3H/38/

Answer (score 1):

When you put the code in your page, either place it at the end of the page, before the closing body tag, or wrap it in a document ready handler:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Your code here
});
```

On jsFiddle.net, the onLoad option on the left automatically wraps your code in a window.load call:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#sub').hover(function () {

    // Gurantee that height of sub-menu is 0, cant be seen
    // behind main menu
    var height = $("#slide").height();
    if (height > 0) {
        $('#slide').css('height', '0');
    } else {
        var clone = $('#slide').clone()
            .css({
                // Ensures that the sub-menu can not be 
                // found by the cursor before its parent
                // is hovered
                'visibility': 'hidden',
                // Sub-menu takes up exactly the required 
                // amount of space
                'height': 'auto'
        })
        // Add the new created class to the HTML document    
        .addClass('slideClone')
            .appendTo('body');

        //$("'slide").css({,'visibility':'hidden','height':'auto'});
        //var newHeight = $("#slide").height();
        var newHeight = $(".slideClone").height();
        $(".slideClone").remove();

        $('#slide').css('height', newHeight + 'px');
    }
});

$('#sub2').hover(function () {
    var height = $("#slide2").height();
    if (height > 0) {
        $('#slide2').css('height', '0');
    } else {
        var clone = $('#slide2').clone()
            .css({
            'position': 'absolute',
                'visibility': 'hidden',
                'height': 'auto'
        })
            .addClass('slideClone')
            .appendTo('body');

        var newHeight = $(".slideClone").height();
        $(".slideClone").remove();

        $('#slide2').css('height', newHeight + 'px');
    }
});
```